# Kafka consumer doesn't consume more then 200 per second

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We subscribe to a kafka producer with our consumer and in our implementation we are stuck consuming at a maximum of 200 events per second.

For testing we receive bytes and don't do any deserialization and discard them immediately and still we are stuck at a maximum of ~200/s

Our consumer config is as follows:

sbt (v0.13.5): `"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "1.0.1"`

```
val props: Properties = new Properties()
props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "some-client")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "<list-of-kafka-brokers:6668>")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "3000")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, "64")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, "50")
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, "2000")
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.RECEIVE_BUFFER_CONFIG, "102400")
```

Any idea what could cause our consumer to max process only 200 max?

PS: our machine is 16gb ram with 8 cores and 4gb JVM heap space

Comment: A stupid but necessary question: do you have more than 200 messages/second incoming into the queue (or pre-filled for a long run)? It is impossible to consume anything from an empty queue. Another question: what is the average size of one event? In other words what's your throughput in bytes per second rather than messages per second? It is unlikely but you might have just huge events that saturate your network or I/O.

Comment: @SergGr the event max size is 1kb, we have over 500/s incoming. Not sure about consuming something from an empty queue.

Comment: multiple partitions/consumer groups?

Comment: out of curiosity how is performing without the last 4 properties?